# Grouping multiple internet lines

Tags: networking, load-balancing, bandwidth

I have a multiple internet lines each with a different speed.
I want to Grouping them to be like a on line with all of them speed.
I hear about loadbalancer, it could be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the broadness of your question: yes, it's possible. The limitation is that each session will run over a single one of the Internet uplinks. To make use of them all you'll need multiple sessions and some load-balancing mechanism.

Comment: How can I do that??

Comment: One way is to buy a load balancer and configure it appropriately. Decent firewalls also support load balancing.